# Date Limitation PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to separate time from the given string date & time. I simply tried with following example.

```
$time = '2014-01-20 10:45:45';
echo '<br>'.$finalTime = date("H:i:s",strtotime($time));
echo '<br>'.$date = date("d F Y",strtotime($time));
```

I am getting correct date and time.

```
10:45:45
20 January 2014
```

But when I tried with given string, no correct result.

```
$time = '1899-12-30 19:30:00';
echo '<br>'.$finalTime = date("H:i:s",strtotime($time));
echo '<br>'.$date = date("d F Y",strtotime($time));
```

PHP is always returning me following result.

```
00:00:00
01 January 1970
```

I am not sure whether is there any limitation on date function that is not returning 1899. Is that so?

Comment: [It would work if you were on 64-bit machine.](http://3v4l.org/3S8I3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DateTime` and [`DateTime::format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php):

```
$time = '1899-12-30 19:30:00';
$dt = new DateTime($time);
echo $dt->format('d F Y H:i:s');
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/fM22Z

The [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/strtotime) method is limited by the Unix epoch, which is Jan 1, 1970.

**Update:** As Mark comments below, your code *would* work all the way back to 1901 (as a negative timestamp), see here: http://3v4l.org/CSJte

Comment: Negative values for unix timestamps will give dates prior to 1970, but only as far back as 1901 as a 32-bit signed integer

Comment: @MarkBaker Interesting. Updated answer, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your date is before the unix epoch. [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) allows you to work around that.

```
$dt = new DateTime("1899-12-30 19:30:00");
echo $dt->format("d F Y");
echo $dt->format("h:i:s");
```

Comment: +1 for the 'before unix epoch' explanation.